# Inverse Square Law and Proportion question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this the correct derivation for this proportional relationship?

$\frac {intensity_1} {intensity_2} = \frac {distance_1} {distance_2}$

I think the first step is to move all to LHS and equal one to show the steps that two spheres, different in size, have same intensity:

$a = $intensity inner sphere 1, $b = $intensity outer sphere 2,$ r_n = $radius sphere n

$\frac {a 4 \pi r_{1}^2 r_{2}^2} {b 4\pi r_{2}^2 r_{2}^2} = 1$

then assume:

$r_1 = 1, r_1^2 = 1$

then reduce:

$b = \frac {a} {r^2}$

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law) states "the surface area of a sphere (which is 4πr2) is proportional to the square of the radius" ... "it is spread out over an area that is increasing in proportion to the square of the distance from the source. Hence, the intensity of radiation passing through any unit area (directly facing the point source) is inversely proportional to the square of the distance from the point source"

[image: a]

Comment: Can you define your variables? I am having a bit of trouble following your proof. But, the general idea is, intensity is a measure of how much "stuff" passes through a unit area in a unit time. If the total amount of "stuff" is conserved, then the intensity is inversely proportional to area. But area is proportional to radius squared, so the inverse square law follows.

Comment: Conserved? Is this why $\frac {4\pi r^2}{r^2} = 1$? Still confused about that statement

Comment: @DanDan0101 variables labled

Answer (score 0):

Reference to your diagram

$$ \dfrac{I}{I_1}=\dfrac{r_1^2}{r^2}$$
where $I$ can be intensity and radial distance $r$ in spherical coordinates.